# DataTable + entering row at specific row in C#

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a Data table and I want to enter a row at the beginning and end of the table how can I achieve this:

C# code:

```
Guid tempGuid1 = new Guid();
dt1.Rows[0]["ID"] = tempGuid1;
dt1.Rows[0]["Name"] = "Select a WishList";
Guid tempGuid = new Guid();
dt1.Rows.Add(tempGuid, "Create a new WishList");
```

Ok after I fill the table I want to enter a brand new row at top of the table

```
Guid tempGuid1 = new Guid();
dt1.Rows[0]["ID"] = tempGuid1;
dt1.Rows[0]["Name"] = "Select a WishList";
```

and than at the end of the table

```
Guid tempGuid = new Guid();
dt1.Rows.Add(tempGuid, "Create a new WishList");
```

I can enter at the end but the brand new row giving me problems, currently the code overwrites the top row which is `row[0]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`InsertAt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowcollection.insertat.aspx) method to insert a new row at the position you want.

Referencing `row[0]` means you are overwriting the data already there, as you have discovered.

```
DataRow newRow = dt1.NewRow();
newRow["ID"] = tempGuid1;
newRow["Name"] = "Select a WishList";
dt1.Rows.InsertAt(newRow, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the DataRowCollections "InsertAt" method.  It accepts a data row and an integer representing the row index at which the row should be inserted.  So you can use this code:

```
Guid tempGuid = new Guid();
DataRow firstRow = dt1.NewRow();
firstRow["ID"] = tempGuid;
firstRow["Name" = "Select a Wishlist";
dt1.InsertAt(firstRow, 0);
```